# Gradle cookbook "creating source and resource directories" for other plugin

Tags: gradle

I can see following in cookbook

```
task "create-dirs" << {
    sourceSets.all*.java.srcDirs*.each { it.mkdirs() }
    sourceSets.all*.resources.srcDirs*.each { it.mkdirs() }
}
```

how can i list same for web plugin

Answer (score 6):

In gradle 2.1, it'll look something like this ( think this also applies to gradle 1.0)

[How I figured this out](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/source_directory_creation_for_java_projects_in_gradle_1_0_milestone_9)

```groovy
task 'create-dirs' << {
    sourceSets.all { set ->
        set.allSource.srcDirs.each {it.mkdirs()}
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tweaked it a bit into such single liner (the task's body): `sourceSets*.allSource.srcDirs.flatten()*.mkdirs()`

Answer (score 2):

In Gradle 0.9.1 the war plugin only adds a single directory, which is defined in the convention object and not part of a source set.

So the original task you posted could be expanded to this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

task "create-dirs" << {
   webAppDir.mkdirs()
   sourceSets.all*.java.srcDirs*.each { it.mkdirs() }
   sourceSets.all*.resources.srcDirs*.each { it.mkdirs() }
}
```