# How to define custom source set without defining it's path explicitly in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

It is written in manual:

[image]

I.e. that `src/sourceSet/java` is a default path for "Java source for the given source set".

How to utilize this? Suppose I wish to create source set `demo`.

Can I write

```
sourceSets {
    demo {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/demo/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/demo/resources'
        }
    }
}
```

Can I write somehow without explicit paths?

May be I not required to write anything, just put files into demo subfolder?

**UPDATE**

I have tested

```
sourceSets {
    demo {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/demo/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/demo/resources'
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
sourceSets {
    demo {
        java
        resources
    }
}
```

and

```
sourceSets {
    demo
}
```

In all cases running `gradle build` does not cause sources compiled.

`build.gradle` file is follows:

```
group 'net.inthemoon.tests'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

sourceSets {
    demo {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/demo/java'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/demo/resources'
        }
    }
}
```

Sample project: https://github.com/dims12/MultipleSourceRoots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gradle default tasks will not build non-default source sets unless there is an explicit dependency on them in the main chain. In order to compile your `demo` classes you'd have to call `gradle demoClasses` as per cricket_007's answer - or better yet, just do `gradle build demo` which will also put the generated classes in the target jar.

All you need is this :

```
sourceSets {
    demo
}
```

... and the `build demo` task will indeed create any missing directory as expected, unless you have some weird permission scheme in effect.

Now I have looked at your git project and it seems your demo source set depends on the main classes. You need to make this dependency clear (i.e. add them to the `demo` classpaths) to avoid compilation errors :

```
sourceSets {
    main
    demo {
      compileClasspath += main.output
      runtimeClasspath += main.output
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you take such names as `compileClasspath` and `runtimeClasspath`?

Comment: @Dims it's defined here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet:compileClasspath. There are plenty of examples on how to use this online.

Answer (score 3):

This should be all you need:

```
sourceSets {
    demo
}
```

More configuration may be needed to define the dependencies of these sources and where they should be used.

Comment: @Dims can you please say what doesn't work if you do `gradle build demo` ?

Comment: then run `gradle compileDemo` or look for tasks added to your project.

Answer (score 1):

Brand new IntelliJ Java Gradle project. (Disclaimer: there was a setting to auto-create empty source directories automatically that I checked)

[image: content roots]

Upon adding this, it created that demo directory and the resources under it.

```
sourceSets {
    demo
}
```

[image: intellij snapshot]

To compile your additional `sourceSet` you can run

```
gradlew demoClasses
```

Comment: Try use `Gradle` from command line. `IntelliJ` reads `build.gradle` independently and may interpret it differently than `Gradle` itself. I know it works better somehow here, which doesn't matter. Question is about `Gradle`.

Comment: @Dims You may need a [Gradle task](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25853817/2308683) to make those directories, but the `java` plugin should default to making both the `src/sourceSet/main` and `src/sourceSet/resources` folders without an otherwise specified

Comment: Compilation process should make these directories. I am speaking about directories under `build` subdirectory.

Comment: What do you mean? The `build` task would look at the sourceSet and compile the files to `/build/classes/sourceSet` and `/build/resources/sourceSet`

Comment: Ideally, you should be using a multi-module setup to bundle all your resources&classes, and not a single multi-sourceSet module.

Comment: @cricket_007 I second that. Gradle is good at inter-module dependencies, inter-source sets dependencies aren't nearly as straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [gradle's documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N157F6) and already mentioned in the other answers, to add a new source set it should be sufficient to write:

```
sourceSets {
    demo {
        compileClasspath += main.output
    }
}
```

The Java plugin will automatically add corresponding `compileDemoJava` and `processDemoResources` tasks to your build.

To automatically execute these tasks during your regular build, you can add a dependency to the default tasks:

```
tasks.compileJava.dependsOn compileDemoJava
```

or the other way around:

```
tasks.compileJava.finalizedBy compileDemoJava
```

To add the output of your new source set to some distribution file, you will however need to define a corresponding task and declare this task's output to be an artifact of your build:

```
task demoJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.demo.output
}

artifacts {
    archives demoJar
}
```

See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_management.html#N13913) for further reading on the publishing stuff

---

**UPDATE**:

- Added `main.output` to compile classpath of demo source set as already suggested by @Amine