# Using a Custom SourceSet in Gradle

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

According to [this from the official docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:custom_java_source_sets) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37877694/1151724), defining a new source set should be as simple as (in kotlin):

```
sourceSets {
    create("demo") {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output
    }
}
```

*The second reference also explicitly claims this can now be used in building a jar.*  However, while the above does not throw an error, actually trying to use the new source set anywhere does.  Minimal example (generated with `gradle init` -> "kotlin application" and project name "foobar"):

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm").version("1.3.21")
    application
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
}

application {
    mainClassName = "foobar.AppKt"
}

sourceSets {
    create("demo") {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output
    }
}
```

I've removed configuration of the `test` source set since it isn't relevant here. The `src` directory looks like this (which is a bit non standard, but I think fine for the discussion):

```
src
├── demo
│   └── Demo.kt
└── main
    └── foobar
        └── App.kt
```

Ideally, I'd like to have completely separate source trees (but this question is not specifically about that).  What this builds makes sense in relation to the configuration above, but it is not really the goal.  To do that, I want to add a custom jar or two.<sup>1</sup>

Unfortunately though, the `demo` source set can't be referenced in the gradle script.

```
val jar by tasks.getting(Jar::class) {
    manifest { attributes["Main-Class"] = "DemoKt" }

    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM:
    from(sourceSets["demo"].get().output)
    dependsOn(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
    from({
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().filter { it.name.endsWith("jar") }.map { zipTree(it) }
    })
}
```

This fat jar task definition is [taken from the gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:creating_uber_jar_example) and I've used much before.
As is, gradle chokes:

```
Script compilation errors:


  Line 28:      from(sourceSets["demo"].get().output)
                                    ^ Unresolved reference.
```

If I change that line to:

```
from(sourceSets.demo.get().output)
```

Which is the syntax used with `sourceSets.main`, then the error becomes:

```
 Line 28:      from(sourceSets.demo.get().output)
                            ^ Unresolved reference: demo
```

**How am I supposed to work with the custom source set?**

---

1. I am aware of the gradle `subproject` pattern and have used it to do much the same thing, but I'd prefer the simple separate source sets solution, which does I think meet all three criteria for such mentioned [in that doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:custom_java_source_sets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sourceSets` property (an extension property for `Project`) returns a `SourceSetContainer` which extends `NamedDomainObjectContainer<SourceSet>`. The latter interface defines  [`get(String)`](https://gradle.github.io/kotlin-dsl-docs/api/org.gradle.kotlin.dsl/org.gradle.api.-named-domain-object-collection/get.html) (an operator extension function) which is what allows you to use the `["..."]` syntax. That method returns `T` directly, meaning you should just be using:

```kotlin
from(sourceSets["demo"].output)
```

The reason you have to use `get()` when using `sourceSets.main` is because you're getting a `NamedDomainObjectProvider<SourceSet>` which *wraps* the source set.

You can also get the custom source set via delegation

1. When creating it:

   ```kotlin
   val demo by sourceSets.creating { /* configure */ }
   ```
2. Or some time after creating it:

   ```kotlin
   val demo by sourceSets
   ```